# How should MassTransit's IConsumeObserver be used?

Tags: masstransit

I'm having trouble using the IConsumeObserver in MassTransit3. I've written a very simple observer that just prints a message to the console pre and post consume, but the messages aren't displayed and it seems that code never gets called (breakpoints within it aren't hit).

```
public class ConsumeObserver : IConsumeObserver
{
    public async Task ConsumeFault<T>(ConsumeContext<T> context, Exception exception) where T : class
    {
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("ConsumeObserver.ConsumeFault");
    }

    public async Task PostConsume<T>(ConsumeContext<T> context) where T : class
    {
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("ConsumeObserver.PostConsume");
    }

    public async Task PreConsume<T>(ConsumeContext<T> context) where T : class
    {
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("ConsumeObserver.PreConsume");
    }
}
```

Curiously, I've implemented a similar receive observer, and it does get called as I would expect.

```
public class ReceiveObserver : IReceiveObserver
{
    public async Task PostReceive(ReceiveContext context)
    {
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("ReceiveObserver.PostReceive");
    }

    //Other methods omitted for brevity        
}
```

I'm connecting the observers to the bus like this:

```
        var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
        {
            var host = cfg.Host(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMQHost"]), h => { });

            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "Subscriber", e =>
            {
                e.Consumer<SomethingHappenedConsumer>();
                e.UseRetry(Retry.Interval(2, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
            });
        });

        //The callbacks in this observer get called...
        bus.ConnectReceiveObserver(new ReceiveObserver());

        //...but not in these two observers
        bus.ConnectConsumeObserver(new ConsumeObserver());
        bus.ConnectConsumeMessageObserver(new ConsumeSomethingHappenedObserver());
```

Any help in understanding is appreciated. I have put the full source on [GitHub](https://github.com/josephdecock/MassTransitPubSubErrorHandler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the `ConsumeObserver` must be registered on each receive endpoint (with .13). So messages consumed by receive endpoints are not visible by connecting the observer to the bus, unless the observer is also connected to the receive endpoint.

To make this consistent with the `ReceiveObserver`, I'll updating the bus code so that the other observers connect to the receive endpoints as well.